# What does "Failed to execute /init (error -7)" mean?

Tags: linux-kernel

Linux kernel version: 4.18.0-17

I am porting some 4.15 kernel customizations to 4.18, but my 4.18 kernel does not boot.  A stock 4.18 kernel (i.e. the starting point before merging the 4.15 modifications) boots and runs.

The error message is:

Failed to execute /init (error -7)
Starting init: /bin/sh exists but couldn't execute it (error -7)

"errno 7" is "E2BIG 7 Argument list too long"

What does that mean in the context of the kernel starting the init process?

Comment: Are you able to boot a stock 4.18 kernel that you built (without changes)?

Answer (score 0):

If the kernel command line and root file systems is exactly the same as the one you are giving to the kernel version that does boot than the most likely cause is that get_user_pages_remote() is failing here: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/fs/exec.c#L194
Which would imply one of your changes broke memory management.

To get here, just track from try_to_run_init_process() which runs init to all the functions called from it which can return E2BIG. This is the only call site that does not depend on init argument list or environment size - https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v4.18/source/init/main.c#L1001

Having said that, I would first make VERY sure that the kernel command line and root file system are the same.